# How to add a trailing slash when joining paths

Tags: go, filepath

Im making a webapp and I'm trying to write `views/layouts/*.html`
using two vars but filepath.Join only gives `views/layouts` instead of `views/layouts/`

```
var (
    LayoutDir string = filepath.Join("views","layouts")
    TemplateExt string = "*.html"
)
```

then calling

```
f, err:= filepath.Glob(LayoutDir + TemplateExt)
```

And so f contains `views/layouts*.html` instead of `views/layouts/*.html`
How should I solve this and is it a good practice to use filepath.Join in this case?

Comment: You can try a + “/“ + b

Comment: @TiagoPeczenyj Hardcoding a "/" will defeat the whole purpose of using filepath.Join which separates them with an OS specific Separator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`f, err:= filepath.Glob(filepath.Join(LayoutDir, TemplateExt))` should do the trick

or

`LayoutDir string = filepath.Join("views", "layouts") + string(filepath.Separator)`

or

`LayoutDir string = filepath.Join("views", "layouts") + string(os.PathSeparator)`

Comment: Haha yes it will, but I'm still trying to look for a method that adds a trailing slash right into the LayoutDir thereby reducing the need to call filepath.Join over and over again. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @retrologic updated the answer to include options for appending the OS specific separator which is available as const.

Comment: Thank you! @Dylan Reimerink this will do the trick.

Comment: @retrologic, usually you parse the template(s) only once, so OK to use another time filepath.join, imo. Looks cleaner that doing string concatenation with the + sign, to me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough rep to comment - maybe a mod will move my 'answer' to a comment. One quick thing to beware of is this code will produce `views/layouts\` on windows machines... I'd just use `/` instead of filepath.Separator or os.PathSeparator.

Comment: On Windows, use `filepath.ToSlash` on the result to convert `"views/layouts\"` to `"views/layouts/"`